# error message using python magic on Windows XP

Tags: python, python-magic

I followed the instructions here...

https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#dependencies

I ran pip install python-magic and it installed without any issues.  Then I installed cygwin and added C:\cygwin\bin to my system path.  When I run the python interpreter in a Windows command prompt and import magic I get this error...

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import magic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\magic.py", line 161, in <module>
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
>>>
```

Did I miss a step?

Comment: did you copy cygwin1.dll, cygz.dll, and cygmagic-1.dll to C:\Windows\System32? This is probably needed if you're not running Python inside Cygwin.

Comment: @MattDMo: In fact, it explicitly says that in the docs, right in the section he linked…

Comment: @abarnert - right. I was just asking because OP didn't mention it explicitly in the question.

Comment: @MattDMo: Yes, that's why I +1'd your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `python-magic` use `libmagic`,

The `libmagic` [needs](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/a5ebf0d558c3a851c0884d30a0051836f7db0c2a/magic.py#L151) `magic1.dll`,

That `magic1.dll` is in the [file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) package of `gnuwin32`.

Solution 1:

Download `binaries zip` or `setup` package of [file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm), and adding path of `bin` directory of it to `PATH` environment variable.

Solution 2:

Also there is a new [change-set](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/commit/fc73c30c2fd4d17babfd1a7b864c96ba517f6130#diff-1) in code of `python-magic` that fixed the problem and you don't need to [file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) package of `gnuwin32` (just add `bin` directory of `cygwin` to `PATH`), but currently there is not yet in `magic.py` while you install it with `pip install python-magic` or by `pip install python-magic --upgrade`,
So you need to install `python-magic` from [master](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/archive/master.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at this post: http://www.thehackeruniversity.com/2014/02/02/obtain-python-mime-types-windows/

This guy uses Hachoir to find the mime info for binary files.